# #include SimpleMath.h

Tags: c++, math, directx-11

My problem is that I am wanting to get the SimpleMath included into my Visual Studio 2012 project, does anyone know the correctly library for this please ?

I have looked on the internet and have spent considerable time looking and searched stackoverflow if you could help with this it would be appreciated.

```
#include "pch.h"

#include <SpriteGame.h>
#include <SimpleMath.h>

using namespace Microsoft::WRL;
using namespace Windows::UI::Core;
using namespace Windows::Graphics::Display;
using namespace DirectX;
using namespace Platform;

SpriteGame::SpriteGame() :
  d3dDevice ( nullptr )
, d3dDeviceContext ( nullptr )
, swapChain ( nullptr )
, backBufferTarget ( nullptr )
, d3dFeatureLevel ( D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1 )
{

}
```

Comment: Did you look [here](http://directxtk.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: @MikeSeymour The DirectX folder is already included and went through all the settings

Comment: You never asked a direct question, nor did you state the specific *error*. Is it at compile-time (can't find the include files)? Is it link-time (undefined symbol/reference)? We're not (all) mind readers (though I have my suspicions about Mike =P, from some of the answers he's posted in the past).

Comment: @WhozCraig Ahh sorry yea it is saying  error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'SimpleMath.h': No such file or directory

Comment: Then the toolkit has not been added to the project properly for inclusion, and if that is the case, I would  almost guarantee it is likewise not correct for linkage. Review your project include path. If needed turn on verbose compiler output to include paths-searched for include files. You may be surprised.

Comment: @WhozCraig looking into what you suggested now, thanks for the advice.